# Нужна ли запятая после "при"?

Tags: пунктуация

Есть такое предложение: **При нарушении того-то правила(**,**) модератор выдаёт наказание**. Конкретно вопрос с запятой между *того-то* и *модератор* объясните ещё, чтобы больше не было вопросов с этим.

Если так подумать, то можно, наверное, "при" заменить на "если", тогда будет точно запятая, но можно ли так делать? Например, *если нарушить такое-то правило, (_то_) модератор выдаёт наказание.*

Comment: Если при заменить на если, то запятая ставится. Но это никоим образом не влияет на постановку запятой в исходной фразе. Запятая не ставится, наличие запятой – грубая ошибка.

Comment: @Римма, для чего была эта правка? Зачем столько форматирования? Всё основное и так было выделено. Название раскрывало смысл вопроса сильнее, чем "Особенности постановки запятой".

Comment: 1. Заглавие: запятая после "при" - после "при" не требовалось запятой. 2. "При нарушение того-то правила..." - правильно: при нарушении такого-то правила... 3. "Конкретно вопрос с запятой между того-то и модератор" - правильно: конкретно, между "правила" и "модератор".  С уважением

Comment: pinkLama - правка была вполне уместной. Дело не только в форматировании, хотя и оно не лишне тут. Если вы не согласны, то имеете право отменить, но обижаться и выяснять отношения не нужно. После модератора мелкую правку делать не принято, но вам стоит самостоятельно навести порядок в вопросе.

Comment: Вопросов нету, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**При нарушение того-то правила // модератор выдаёт наказание.**

Запятая не нужна, **это простое предложение**. Обстоятельственный оборот является  детерминантом, то есть распространяет не отдельные члены предложения,  а предложение в целом. Простое предложение состоит из двух частей и  строится по схеме "тема ― рема" или "предмет ― сообщение о предмете".

Аналогичное содержание можно выразить с помощью **другой грамматической формы** ― сложноподчиненного предложения: **Если нарушить такое-то правило,  модератор выдаёт наказание.** Здесь два предложения, две предикативные основы (первое предложение безличное инфинитивное), поэтому по правилам ставится запятая.

Есть еще третий вариант с **факультативным обособлением** распространенного оборота: **В случае нарушения такого-то правила,  модератор выдаёт наказание**.

Итак, мы имеем три варианта с разной грамматикой. Интонация предложений сходная (повышение голоса ― пауза ― понижение голоса), но в простом предложении мы имеем скорее не паузу, а перелом интонации, что соответствует отсутствию запятой.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59925/discussion-on-answer-by-sibylla-----).

Answer (score 2):

Правильный вариант: *"При нарушени**и такого-то** правила модератор выдаёт наказание"*.

Запятая не нужна потому, что нет правила, на основании которого её надо ставить, даже предположить на основании какого правила надо её ставить. Есть, правда, такое понятие, как "факультативное обособление" (см. другие примеры). Но оно тоже требует выполнения некоторых условий, во фразе из нет.

Все остальное - это просто неряшливость вашего (или вашего автора) русского языка.

**@Sibylla**, я не понимаю придирок гг. Сержа и Niemand'а (это уже работа для модератора), но у меня своя претензия. Вы даете ответ на вопрос - и обоснование, никак реально не обосновывающее. При чем тут какие-то варианты с разной грамматикой? Грамматика одна, авторская, с ошибками правда. И нужно всего лишь четко ответить, что нет применимого к ситуации правила, по которому там запятая обязательна. А насчет факультативной, это уже что-то умозрительное.

> "При наличии благоприятной погоды, завтра выезжаем в Казань"
>   Здесь возможно факультативное обособление, так как второе предложение
>   имеет законченный смысл. А в приведенном примере структура та же, но
>   второе предложение не является самостоятельным по смыслу.

Это близко к истине. С оговоркой. К сожалению, опять не могу найти прямых рекомендаций, но похоже, дело здесь не столько в законченности основной части фразы, сколько в распространенности самого оборота. В нашем случае это член предложения, обстоятельство причины, в примере же - условие, выраженное громоздким оборотом, которое напрямую трудно трактовать как член предложения, поэтому и обособление возможно. Но по большому счету и здесь оно не нужно. Оборот не настолько осложненный, причин для обособления в общем-то нет. Оно кочует из ресурса в ресурс, первоисточника нет, почему и зачем там эту запятую проставили, нигде не объясняется толком.

А ведь фраза - косноязычная. Ну почему не сказать просто "При благоприятной погоде"? И вопрос с запятой отпадает сам собой. "Наличие" здесь совершенно чуждый живому языку канцеляризм.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59926/discussion-on-answer-by------).